# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException error google play?

Tags: android

If it gives me this error in google play can someone help me please

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:317)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1923)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ... and some source code would be helpful too :)

Comment: I think is about some tab that doesn't exists.

Comment: I do not know what code it ...

Comment: @RajeshCP The trace IS complete.  See the last line, `NativeStart.main()`?

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of code from your activity where you are dealing with the tab host.

Comment: <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>  is that correct?